# error of scala and spark version mismatch in Java maven code from IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run Java/Scala (maven project) from IntelliJ (community 2019.2) on Mackbook pro.

My java:

```
  Java 12.0.2 2019-07-16
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

my code:

```
  SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local"); // error !

  JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

My pom:

```
  <properties>
    <scala.version>2.11.12</scala.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.11.12</scala.binary.version>
    <java.version>12</java.version>
    <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
</properties>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0-M4</version>
    </dependency>


  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My scala and spark are all 2.11, why I still got the error :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
 scala.Predef$.$conforms()Lscala/Predef$$less$colon$less;
```

Based on

```
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845831/nosuchmethoderror-scala-predef-conformslscala-predeflesscolonless
```

I should not have this version mismatch ?

thanks

**UPDATE**
I have installed java11 based on 
https://medium.com/w-logs/installing-java-11-on-macos-with-homebrew-7f73c1e9fadf

but, I got the same error.

```
 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=...

 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.$conforms()Lscala/Predef$$less$colon$less;
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Java 12 is compatible with Java 13. And Java 13 is compatible with Scala versions `2.13.1` and `2.12.9`. If possible, use at most Java 11 (which is compatible with Scala versions `2.13.0, 2.12.4, 2.11.12, 2.10.7` so you should be fine with your `2.11.12`.

Nonetheless, it seems that Spark 3.0 is going to support JDK9+ [SPARK-24417](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24417)

---

Also: please change `scala.binary.version` in your `pom.xml`, it should be

```
<scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
```

instead of

```
<scala.binary.version>2.11.12</scala.binary.version>
```

With that change you can call dependencies without explicit Scala version, that is instead of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

you can say

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have made the changes based on your post but got the same error. thanks

Comment: Also, in the dependency tabs of IntelliJ, I have "Maven: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.12" and "Maven: org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.4.5". Do I need to update them ?

Comment: I do not have Java 11 on my machine.

Comment: dependencies are fine; those changes are not going to fix Java12 related issues; you simply cannot run Scala 2.11 with Java12

Comment: I have change scala to 2.12.9 but got the same error.

Comment: then it might also be the problem with Spark itself which is running on Java8

Comment: please see my updates in OP. I got the same error with java11.

Comment: please, try Java8; personally, I always use Java8 while working with Spark

Comment: I have to use another software tool, which does not work on java8.

Comment: this is the reason why I changed from java 1.8 to java 12.

Comment: it seems that Spark 3.0 is going to support JDK 9+ https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24417